# Form is not Secure when redirecting from Odoo Controller

Tags: python, odoo

can someone help me?

In Odoo when redirecting using Odoo Controller it prompts not Secure only in Chrome Browser.. it is working on other browsers.. for example when login in, it prompts that my Form is not secure even though my SSL is working fine..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

found a general solution that worked for my Odoo installation as well that has a Nginx reverse proxy.

Just add proxy redirect:

proxy_redirect http://$http_host https://$http_host​

Then restart nginx.